# cards with 4 columns bootstrap flexbox joomla

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, flexbox

its my first question here. Im trying to make 4 columns in 1 row in CMS Joomla 3. Link to test site: http://www.chmpolska.pl/1. On main page Joomla module with 8 boxes isn't working properly anymore and i have to make new module. I have the same problem on my other site http://www.psycholog-pebe.pl. I'm trying to use one of codepen ideas, but i cant to set 4 columns in 1 row. Any1 knows how to fix my problem?

```css
.cards {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0.5%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background: #fefff9;
  color: #363636;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0 0 8px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0 0 8px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0 0 8px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
@media (max-width: 1300px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    max-width: 250px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .card:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .card:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .card:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}
.card span {
  display: block;
}
.card .card-summary {
  padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
  text-align: justify;
}
.card .card-header {
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  position: relative;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.card .card-header:hover, .card .card-header:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.card .card-title {
  background: #d63e52;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2.5% 0 2.5% 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .card-title h3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 0 3.5%;
  margin: 3.5%;
}
.card:hover, .card:focus {
  background: white;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.card:hover .card-title, .card:focus .card-title {
  background: #333;
}

card-img-top {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
// stop images from breaking out of their bounding boxes.

* {
  -moz-transition-property: background-color, border-color, box-shadow, color, opacity, text-shadow, -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: background-color, border-color, box-shadow, color, opacity, text-shadow, -o-transform;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color, border-color, box-shadow, color, opacity, text-shadow, -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: background-color, border-color, box-shadow, color, opacity, text-shadow, transform;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
   

 <div class="cards">
          <div class="row">
            <a class="card col-md-3" href="http://www.chmpolska.pl/tokarki-karuzelowe">
                <span class="card-header" style="background-image: url(http://www.chmpolska.pl/images/headers/sg-8-tokarka-karuzelowa-223x167px.png);">
                  <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Tokarki karuzelowe</h3>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span class="card-summary">
                  Maszyny budowane w oparciu o materiały i wyposażenie najwyższej jakości - komponenty: Heidenhain - liniały pomiarowe, Siemens – sterowanie, śruby kulowe KSK Kurim, przekładnia ZF Germany.
                </span>
            </a>
            <a class="card col-md-3" href="http://www.chmpolska.pl/prasy-krawedziowe-cnc">
                <span class="card-header" style="background-image: url(http://www.chmpolska.pl/images/headers/sg-8-prasa-krawdziowa-cnc-230x167px.jpg);">
                  <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Prasy krawędziowe</h3>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span class="card-summary">
                  Prasy krawędziowe CNC tureckiej firmy ERMAKSAN wykorzystują podzespoły renomowanych producentów, takich jak: HOERBIGER, BOSCH-REXROTH, ATOS, HYDAC, SIEMENS oraz PILZ.
                </span>
            </a>
            <a class="card col-md-3" href="http://www.chmpolska.pl/prasy-mimosrodowe">
                <span class="card-header" style="background-image: url(http://www.chmpolska.pl/images/chm-prasa-mimosrodowa-230x156px.png);">
                  <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Prasy mimośrodowe</h3>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span class="card-summary">
                  Prasy mimosrodowe przeznaczone są do wszystkich zwykłych prac prasowania na zimno - np. wycinania, przebijania otworów, obcinania, tłoczenia, prostowania, gięcia, ciągnienia płytkiego, nitowania itd.
                </span>
            </a>
            <a class="card col-md-3" href="http://www.chmpolska.pl/prasy-hydrauliczne">
                <span class="card-header" style="background-image: url(http://www.chmpolska.pl/images/chm-prasa-hydrauliczna-230x167px.png);">
                  <span class="card-title">
                    <h3>Prasy hydrauliczne</h3>
                  </span>
                </span>
                <span class="card-summary">
                  Oferujemy kompletne technologie poprzez dobór oprzyrządowania, wraz z wyborem odpowiedniego typu automatyzacji. Tak, aby otrzymać produkt spełniający najwyższe jakościowe wymagania.
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: add <a> tag inside the `col-md-3` div instead of this `<a class="card col-md-3">`

Comment: @Manish Patel. Thanks for your comment. Ive changed my html code to 1 simple row, but i still have 3 boxes in a row instead of 4 and i dont know how to remove underline from text on hover.